# How much kb has a mb ,some say 1000 some 1024

Tags: php, linux

*HOW MUCH KB HAS A MB ?
GOOGLE SAY 1024 KB IS 1.24 MB
OTHERS SAY 1024 KB IS 1 MB
WHO IS WRONG?*

https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=ssl#q=kb+to+mb

OR

http://www.tnhost.com/tools/k-kb-mb-gb-tb-conveter

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: Sometimes there can be issues converting binary to decimal, thus the different answers. Both are correct depending if you are looking at it as binary or decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `MB` and `MiB`!

See:

1'000 KB = 1 MB (decimal) -> Megabyte (MB)  10^6 Byte = 1 000 000 Byte

1'024 KB = 1 MiB (binary) -> Mebibyte (MiB) 2^20 Byte = 1 048 576 Byte

Thats why you see difference values

Comment: ok,but both sites use same name for values:  Kilobyte to Megabyte , both websites name the values exactly same.whitch is wrong? ,Both sites whey convert Kilobyte to Megabyte ,but the result is different .

Comment: @DionisL the second page have wrong name! It should say: `Mebibyte` See:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Comment: Usually no one is so pedantic to use Mib. The things are so messed up that there is no way of saying whether it is a power of 2 or a power of 10. Memory comes usually, by construction, in amounts that are a power of 2.

Comment: @DionisL finally it's what Paul92 said!

Answer (score 0):

As Rizier123 said google use 1024 Kilobyte = 1.24 Megabyte and

1024 KibiByte = 1 Mebibyte

so the 2 websites use same natation for different aspects.
If we take google values as standards, then **second** site must change his notations to:

**KibiByte to  Mebibyte**

so ppls do not get wrong